# How is syntax for comment executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my project directory `app/assets/stylesheets`, I saw some syntax like below:

```
//= require blueimp/css/blueimp-gallery.min.css
//= require slick/slick.css
//= require slick/slick-theme.css
```

and

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require animate/animate.css
 *= require style
 *= require font-awesome
 */
```

These are executed, but isn't it way of commenting?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a comments. This is [manifest lines](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#manifest-files-and-directives).